# Thunderbird 52.9.1 can not start on Ubuntu 14.04 with "GenerateDump cloned child" error

Tags: 14.04, email, thunderbird, ldap

Just in the past few days, my thunderbird immediately crash and refuses to start on my Ubuntu 14.04 box (xfce, with LDAP). It gives the following error

```
fangq@taote:~$ thunderbird 
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 7312
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

I can't be sure, but this likely started after an update.

If I use "sudo thunderbird", it can start without a problem, but I can't see my emails (apparently).

Strangely, I can x2go to another 14.04 machine, with the same version of thunderbird, I could start thunderbird without an error. Both machines share the same home directory/user account and the email folders. I don't know why it refuses to start on one but not the other.

[thunderbird crash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3L8v.pnges)

the strace dump can be found here

http://kwafoo.coe.neu.edu/~fangq/share/temp/thunderbird_crash.txt

Please help! can't get work done without a working thunderbird. thanks

Comment: never mind, the issue was fixed. the crash was a result of missing nscd service in the background. Although nscd service was set to start at boot-time, but for some reason, it did not start, and as long as there is no /usr/bin/nscd running in the system, thunderbird refuses to start. This was a known issue and known workaround: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292127